# How to synch 3 Radio Groups (without handling 3 OnClick()S)?

Tags: delphi

I have 3 radio groups which I display on different tabsheets of a single form app, but they basically all have the same underlying functionality (and only one can be visible to the user at a time).

That is to say, if the user selects a new Radio Button of any of them, I want to programatically update the `ItemIndex`of the other two, to match.

BUT, I don't want to execute the `OnClick()` function three times.

Is there a an easy way to do this, or should I just use a single radio group and keep changing it's `Parent`, `Top` and `Left` as the user changes the visible tab?

The App currently has no menu, so it seems ugly to add one just for this.

Comment: Just create the 3 radio groups and implement only ONE OnClick handler and point the 3 radio groups to the OnClick handler?

Comment: +1 @whosrdaddy That is what I did but the event handler got called 3 times - so presumably is is being called even when I programatically changed the ItemIndex, not just when the user clicks the GUI.

Comment: in the event handler, first remove the event handler of all 3 radio groups, change item indexes and restore event handlers...

Comment: OR make a boolean flag "inside event handler" and only do the work, if it is the 1st call. Or think if it is really big problem to have it called thrice, if you do not have extra code in the handler but only assignments to ItemIndex.

Comment: OR consider reorganizing your UI. Having identical components with identical functionality on multiple tab sheets is not a good idea. If you have common elements (like data filtering) that the end user should always see, move them to a panel outside the tab control. In `OnClick` check for the active tab sheet and act accordingly. It's much cleaner to maintain.

Comment: A much better approach is to separate the GUI from the state ownership. For example MVC.

Comment: @david - TDataset apporach is using (well, perhaps abusing) db-aware level as a ready-made framework for that separation :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 3 radiogroups but only one event handler and assign it to all radiogroups:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroupClick(Sender: TObject);

var Index : Integer;

begin
 RadioGroup1.OnClick := nil;
 RadioGroup2.OnClick := nil;
 RadioGroup3.OnClick := nil;
 Index := TRadioGroup(Sender).ItemIndex;
 RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := Index;
 RadioGroup2.ItemIndex := Index;
 RadioGroup3.ItemIndex := Index;
 RadioGroup1.OnClick := RadioGroupClick;
 RadioGroup2.OnClick := RadioGroupClick;
 RadioGroup3.OnClick := RadioGroupClick;
end;
```

Comment: I'd moved `OnClick :=` and `ItemIndex :=` lines to separate procedures.
Also i'd add try-finally around `OnClick` flip-flopping.

Comment: Yes this can be refactored offcourse. I don't see the need for try finally since the event handler is no longer there?

Comment: for example - in some distand future for some weird reason - different boxes would happen to have different ItemsCount. Or Sender would be some 4th groupbox for an accident.

Comment: Slightly less gross, and fewer lines of code is to set a boolean field in your form to true and exit the on-click when it's true:
if FBusy then exit:
FBusy := true;
// do click handling
FBusy := false;

Comment: @WarrenP that's what i mentioned in top-level comments. Though i'd incapsulate it as a procedure-local variable

Comment: That would defeat the purpose.  If it's procedure local, it's on the stack.  Two different calls create two different locals. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use in-memory TDataset and a number of TDBRadioGroup widgets

- http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/dbctrls/tdbradiogroup.html
- http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBCtrls_TDBRadioGroup.html